# Creating closed groups of users using Parse

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

I'm really new to Swift and Parse in general, but I'm trying to build a project that lets users create a group and then invite their friends to it, sort of like how a Fantasy Football league works but simpler.

I can get people to be able to create their accounts, and I have an empty Class table called Groups, but I'm not sure the best way to let populate that table so that 
1) A user can create a new group
2) A friend could join that group if they know the objectID
3) I can populate a table with all the groups a user belongs to

I'm not sure if within the Groups class I should have a column that stores an array of all the members in a group or what. I think I can figure out the actual coding if someone helps me out with the best way to structure the classes and pointer/relationships if needed.

Any help would be really appreciated, even if it's just a link to a video tutorial or something. Thanks!

Comment: Relationship, not array. What is the group for? What can the people in the group do? How are people invited / added?

Comment: @Wain The group would be a group of friends trying to guess the progression of the NFL playoffs (kinda late, but it's taken me a while to try to learn this stuff). So each member in the group will try to predict which teams will make it through each week, so they would just submit their guesses at the beginning then really just check back each week to see how many "points" they got. Ideally there could be independent groups so friends can play against each other. I haven't figured out how they will be invited yet though :/

Answer (score 0):

So I'd have a group class which has a relationship to user. I'd have a class called ballot which represents the weekly 'vote'. There is one instance per week. You could keep old ones so you have a record of the results. The ballot has a relationship to a vote class. There is one vote instance per user in the group per ballot. The vote has a pointer to the user and a record of the choice made (team name). It could also have the points awarded.